# How to reference conflicted SObject Name?

Tags: apex, sobject, compile-error

It seems that there are two different `Location` objects:

- `global class Location extends SObject`
- `global class System.Location`

Because System is the default namespace, I am not sure how to refer to the SObject *Location* in my `Apex` code.

Example (in Location trigger):

```
Map<Id, Location> newLocations = (Map<Id, Location>) Trigger.newMap;
```

> Incompatible types since an instance of `Map<Id,SObject>` is never an instance of `Map<Id,System.Location>`

Is there any way for me to reference the `Location` SObject?

Comment: I'm not aware of a standard Location object, nor do I see it in the documentation. Are you sure you have the right API name for Location?

Comment: Yes I am sure.

My trigger class is on "Location" SObject

Comment: I'm really curious about this `Location` SObject. If I try to add a trigger on it in my org I get:  `Invalid type: Schema.Location`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever there's a conflict, you can usually rely on Schema to help you sort things out.

```
Map<Id, Schema.Location> locations = (Map<Id, Schema.Location>)Trigger.newMap;
```

However, this won't work if you define a class named "Schema", so make sure that you never, ever do that, unless you want to lose all access to the Schema methods, since it cannot be resolved any other way.